# Rename columns by another pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to rename column name using another dataframe.

df_A is

```
#                a   b   x 
# date
# 2017-11-01     65  12  1
# 2017-11-02     26  1   5
# 2017-11-03     47  5   6
```

df_B is

```
# keys  names
#    a    X   
#    b    Y  
#    x    Z
```

From these, I want to get df_c.
df_c

```
#                X   Y   Z 
# date
# 2017-11-01     65  12  1
# 2017-11-02     26  1   5
# 2017-11-03     47  5   6
```

I think it is easy to do, and may be use dict, but i donno what to do.
Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Create dictionary by `zip` and pass to `rename`:

```
df_A = df_A.rename(columns=dict(zip(df_B['keys'], df_B['names'])))
```

Comment: Oh, yes yes!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use `map`:

```
In [1196]: d = df_B.set_index('keys')['names'].to_dict()
In [1203]: df_A.columns = df_A.columns.map(d)
```